# Accessing header data and treating the error codes in Angular http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

This is how I handle my routing in Angular. I have a couple of files where all the needed data about each route is stored and I iterate over the data like this. .html requests are for loading templates and .action for AJAX requests.

What I need to do is treat all the cases where the server doesn't succeed (300, 400, 500 etc). I googled all I thought relevant found some info about it but nothing seems relevant or clear enough. How exactly do I access the header data of a request?

```
Application.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider', '$httpProvider',

    function($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) 
    {

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');

        for (var i=0; i < applicationRoutes.length; i++) {

            if (applicationRoutes[i].hasInitialData)
            {
                $routeProvider.when('/' + applicationRoutes[i].path + '.html', {

                    templateUrl: applicationRoutes[i].path + '.html',
                    controller: applicationRoutes[i].controller + ' as ' + applicationRoutes[i].controllerAlias,
                    resolve: {
                        initData : ['Initialize', '$route', function(Initialize, $route)
                        {
                            //console.log($route.current.$$route);
                            return Initialize.serverData('/' + $route.current.$$route.pathBase);
                        }]
                    },
                    pathBase: applicationRoutes[i].path

                }).otherwise('/404');
            }
            else
            {
                $routeProvider.when('/' + applicationRoutes[i].path + '.html', {

                    templateUrl: applicationRoutes[i].path + '.html',
                    controller: applicationRoutes[i].controller + ' as ' + applicationRoutes[i].controllerAlias,
                    pathBase: applicationRoutes[i].path

                }).otherwise('/404');

            }

        }

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    }

]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I cant see your server calls, but assuming you have rolled up a Service to call the endpoints with $http remember you can use a fail handler as the second parameter of the promise so

```
$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

meaning you can do this

```
    $http(req).then(function(someData){/*This is the success*/},function(reason){/*the reason holds the reason it faild, reason.data etc */});
```

Comment: you are corrrect, however what i needed at the time was a way to access the headers of requests handled by routing. i've since then managed to handle the http ones

Comment: You can also use `.catch(errorHandler)` instead of the second callback in your `.then()`.